# splitcontainer with treeview

Tags: .net, vb.net, winforms

when i click to a node in the treeview i want to see it's corresponding form in the splitcontainer.panel2,there have diffrent nodes and forms.if any one knows please help me

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
Sub ShowFormInPanel(form as Form,panel as Panel)
Form.TopLevel = False

For Each Cont As Control In panel.Controls
    If Cont IsNot form Then Cont.Visible = False
Next

If Not panel.Controls.Contains(form) Then
    panel.Controls.Add(form)
    form.FormBorderStyle = Windows.Forms.FormBorderStyle.None
    form.Dock = DockStyle.Fill
    form.Show()
Else
    form.Visible = True
End If
End Sub
```

First you have to create an empty panel in the splitcontainer. and then In the "NodeClick" event of the treeview all you have to do is:

ShowFormInPanel(Form, Panel)

NOTE: Take care with memory, because this doesn't dispose closed forms, it just hides them.